# Matlab string variable

Tags: matlab

I am having a problem with this question:

[image: This is the question]

I have written a set of scripts, but I have an issue writing it in terms of a function and script file.

The following line is required but I don't know how to classify the data for `bmiT`, which the category each BMI value should be in.

```
function [bmiV, bmiT, lo_wt, hi_wt] = W3Q1_BMI_Calculator(ht, wt)
```

The code I have written is:

[image: Here]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please post your code as text within the question. See [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for how to write a good question

Comment: Also looks like homework to me. Not a problem per se but posting what you've done and where you are stuck is going to get a better response. w.r.t. your code you can have elseif on one line and you need to think about the if conditions because there is a lot of duplication. The second (16.5<bmiV) will always be true as the first (bmiV<16.5) if statement has already caught the low numbers. Also too many fprintf statements - just do it once at the end. You're nearly there, just set bmiT to the category value and return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guice, the string that you are supposed to return is a statement/classification , like  "severely underweight". In order to return it simply include in each of your if statements the declaration for `bmiT`. Example:

```
if (35 < bmiV)&&(bmiV <= 40)
    fprintf('You are Obesity Class III');
    bmiT = 'Obesity Class III';
```

Note, that if your function is called:

`function [bmiV, bmiT, lo_wt, hi_wt] = W3Q1_BMI_Calculator(ht, wt)`

you don't need to let the user input the hight and weight inside the function. Secondly, if you use your `if` statements without one `>=` or `<=` you will be missing a value.

If you want to make your code much lighter you can write the `fprintf` after the `if` statements and write `elseif` instead of having that sort of 'recursive' structure.

Comment: MATLAB uses single quotes instead of double quotes as string delimiters.

Comment: Yes, but new MatLab versions support both. Anyway it is definitely better sticking to the single quotes.

Comment: There is no "better", if you want to use the string variable type then use double quotes, if you want to use character arrays then use single quotes. They are no interchangeable, but they are both valid for different purposes.

Comment: Ah, @PabloJeken, I didn't know that. Thanks for the update.